# I having problems when installing Steam: Steam needs to install these additional packages:

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386

Press return to proceed with the installation: 
..........
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-13+deb11u6).
libegl1 is already the newest version (1.3.2-1).
libegl1 set to manually installed.
libgbm1 is already the newest version (20.3.5-1).
libgbm1 set to manually installed.
libgl1 is already the newest version (1.3.2-1).
libgl1 set to manually installed.
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (20.3.5-1).
libgl1-mesa-dri set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.2.131.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Press return to continue:
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your package versions match an oldstable Debian system, not Ubuntu*